Minimum is always transparent in ListDensityPlot3D
Here is a minimal example of what I'm struggling with. The following code:
ListDensityPlot3D[{{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, OpacityFunction -> 1]

gives the following output: 
Notice that even though I've set OpacityFunction -> 1, the regions with value zero are transparent. The same thing happens when I try any other OpacityFunction, and when I try setting OpacityFunctionScaling -> False... every time, the values that are close to the minimum of my data are completely transparent. To be clear, this is not what I want.
The one thing I've tried which works in some cases is to set OpacityFunction -> None instead, but this makes things entirely opaque, which is not desirable, and it also doesn't even work in the case of the actual data I'm trying to plot for some reason.
For context, this is in Mathematica 14.0.0.0, on Mac OS X ARM (64 bit) (specifically, the M2 Pro chip). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE. Then, this doesn't seem to be related to Mac, v12.3 and v14.1  on windows behaves like so, too. And, this is harder than I thought, I felt that e.g. OpacityFunction -> Function[f, 0.5 + f/2] should work but it doesn't! Not sure about the reason, waiting for someone more knowledgable…

Try: OpacityFunction -> None

@DanielHuber This is already mentioned in the question.

From the docs: ListDensityPlot3D by default generates colorized output, mainly intended continuous values.  and array should be an array of real numbers; positions where array is not a real number are rendered transparently. 

@Syed But I think 0 is Real…?

Head[0] gives Integer and Head[0.] gives Real.

@Syed Oh I should have wrote "0 is real"… And //N doesn't fix the code. (BTW I believe this has been automatically done inside ListDensityPlot3D. )

Ah, seems that I'm too tired yesterday. As usual, it's always a good idea to check the actual expression of the graphic. With InputForm, or Ctrl+Shift+i, we will see that:
…
ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= 0.5, 
  Opacity[If[-2.2250738585072014*^-308 <= -1. + 2. #1 < 1.0000000000000002, 
             0.01, 0.5, 0], 
   ColorData["WL13DefaultDensityGradient"][-1. + 2. #1]], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]] & )
…

See the If there? If $f<0.5$, the color will be RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0] i.e. transparent. (Don't forget that by default the function value is scaled to $0\leq f\leq 1$ in ListDensityPlot3D. ) If $f\geq 0.5$ (#1 >= 0.5), the function value is again rescaled to $[0,1]$ by -1. + 2. #1 and fed into the color function. This is true even if we use a customized opacity function:
ListDensityPlot3D[{{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, 0.5 + f/2]]
(*
 …
ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= 0.5, 
    Opacity[Function[f, 0.5 + f/2][-1. + 2. #1], 
     ColorData["WL13DefaultDensityGradient"][-1. + 2. #1]], 
          RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]] & )
 …
 *)

So the solution is simple. Just make a replacement on the output with a desired ColorFunction:
opafunc = Function[f, 0.5 + f/2];
colorfunc = ColorData["WL13DefaultDensityGradient"];
ListDensityPlot3D[{{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 
     1}}}] /. (ColorFunction -> _) :> 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[opafunc[#], colorfunc[#]] &)



This appears to work, thanks!

@VilasWinstein Glad it helps. BTW you don't need to accept that fast, it's OK to wait for a day or even longer to see if someone comes up with better solutions :) .

Okay, I un-accepted it, I'll check back in a day or so.

If you have {0,1} data only, you can try the following hack as a workaround:
data = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}};
cols = ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"][1 - #] & /@ {0, 1};

MapThread[
  ArrayMesh[#1
    , MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Thin, Gray}, 3 -> Opacity[0.3, #2]}
    , Axes -> True
    , DataRange -> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}
    , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}
    ] &
  , {
   {data, 1 - data}
   , {Last@cols, First@cols}
   }
  ] // Show




My data is in the interval [0,1], so this doesn't work directly. Can something like this work for more general data? And is it as fast as ListDensityPlot3D? I have a few million data points.

ArrayPlot3D might also be useful. It would be best to load a representative sample of your data.

ArrayPlot3D seems to scale much worse than ListDensityPlot3D, it takes a long time to render and the resulting graphics seems much more heavy (causes more lag on my computer when turning it around, etc). It also has lots of artifacting, I think derived from the fact that each voxel is rendered separately so when transparency is introduced you can see each individual box (which I don't want). Unfortunately, although it does fix the specific issue mentioned in the question, it won't work for me.
